# Backup file size doesn't match with local file size

Tags: backup, google-drive

My computer is Macbook Pro (Early 2015), and I have 120GB flash storage. I'm backing up my files using Google drive's Backup and Sync, but the amount of storage that it should take place on the Google drive is not the same as what it should be based on its size on computer.
 
I'm backing my Desktop, Documents, and my Pictures folder (including Photos library). Based on the space they take up on my disk, if all of them are backed up it should be around 32GB. But on my Google drive they altogether only take up 4GB. (screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VsA6.jpg) 
 
When I click on a random folder on my drive, it does seem that all contents are there. I'm confused about all this; is this a miscalculation, or is it that not all of my stuff is successfully backed up? My Backup and sync status was set to completed for its sync on my Desktop/Documents/Pictures few weeks ago. I really don't want to be in a situation where I thought I backed my stuff but end up without complete backup; please tell me what's actually going on.

Comment: Does that data consist mostly of photos and videos? If you go to photos.google.com and then click on settings you can choose if you want unlimited space in exchange for allowing google to recompress your pictures/videos if they feel like it.

Comment: Also you can just go to drive.google.com to check which files are in your google drive account.

Comment: It has some photos/videos, but it doesn't take up a majority of total storage.

Comment: Drive is probably compressing and deduplicating the data it's storing, both of which can save a significant amount of space.